# The definition of polar density of a set of primes in a number field

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In Chapter 7 of Marcus' Number Fields, he defines the polar density of a set $A$ of primes in a number field $K$, as follows: if for some positive integer $n$, the $n$-th power of the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_{K, A}(s) = \prod_{P \in A} (1-||P||^{-s})^{-1}$ can be extended to a meromorphic function on some neighborhood (in the complex plane) of $s=1$ , with the order of pole at $s=1$ equal to $m$, then the polar density is defined to be $m/n$.

My question regarding this definition is: why do we expect the existence of a meromorphic extension when RAISING TO A POWER, in the first place?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: In general $\zeta_{K,A}^{\, m}$ is not meromorphic for any $m$. At first the polar density should be $\limsup_{s \to 1,s > 1} \frac{\log \zeta_{K,A}(s)}{\log (s-1)}$ comprised between $[0,1]$. If $K/F$ is Galois and $A$ is (Artin map) a conjugacy class $C$ in the Galois group then $\zeta_{K,A}^{\, |G|}$ is meromorphic with a pole of order $|C|$ and no poles nor zeros on $\Re(s) \ge 1,s \ne 1$ (Chebotarev theorem)